# Taking a bug report from Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-logcat

One of my users has Samsung Galaxy S3 with JellyBean.

I tried to instruct him on sending me a bug report, but apparently, the option doesn't exist on his device.
The normal power + volume up + volume down doesn't work.
There is no option for that in "Developer Options".
The device runs JB, so 3rd party logcat apps don't work.

I prefer not to code or use a bug report library in my app just so Galaxy S3 can send a bug report... 
Anything I missed?
Any 3rd party app that invokes the "send bug report" feature?

Comment: I have such a device, running stock. I get the dialog to send a bug report whenever an app crashes. Is that the report you are talking about?

Comment: I'm not talking about the "force close" dialog - I'm talking about the ability to send a bug report at will (even without a crash).

Comment: Same situation, i am facing.

Comment: This is an old question, but did you ever figure out a solution? I have a user with the same device, now running 4.3. He was able to turn on the "Bug report" option but the system doesn't generate a bug report unless you have an app selected in the "Select app to be debugged" menu. And I think only apps that are running in debug mode (signed with the debug key, not release key) are allowed to be selected. So users can't generate a logcat for production versions anyway. Very frustrating. I might have to send the user a debug version of the APK to get this working. Also what carrier is he using?

Comment: It wasn't solved back then, we found another way to debug the issue.